# When to choose Cassandra over a SQL/Semantic Store solution?

Tags: sql, nosql, cassandra, semantics

I have 30-40 GB of data and 3 developer machines (Core Duo i4, 3GB). The data is a set of graph like structures and I have queries that traverse the graphs. Is there a guideline that could help me to decide to use Cassandra or a classic solution, e.g., SQL or Semantic Store? My current plan is to set up Cassandra and see how does it work but I would like to learn more before starting the installation.

Comment: If you use graph like structure take a look at neo4j or another graph DB: http://neo4j.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use Cassandra for any kind of graph level structure.  It has been about 6 months since I looked into doing something similar so maybe Cassandra has moved on since then but I found it was fundamentally limited by the fact that it only has row level indexes.

For a Graph based structure (assuming a simplistic one arc per row layout) you really need column indexes as well since if you want to traverse the graph you want to be able to start from a particular node `A` and find all the arcs that go from that node (assuming a directed Graph) then you'd have to do a row scan of the entire dataset as there is no built in functionality for saying give me the rows that have `A` in a particular column.

To achieve this you have to effectively design a data layout for Cassandra that gives you an inverted index.  This is somewhat tricky and requires you to know ahead of time the type of queries that you want to answer - answering new types of queries at a later data may be very difficult or impossible if you don't design well.  These [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/benjaminblack/cassandra-basics-indexing) demonstrate the idea but I hope it makes it clear that you effectively have to construct your own indexes.

For Graph structures that can be decomposed to triples consider an RDF store - for more complex structures then consider a full blown Graph Database.  If you really want to do NoSQL you can probably build something on top of a document database as they tend to have much better indexing but again you'll have to think carefully about how you store your data.